# Data Conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have read everything I could find on this topic here and still cannot resolve my error problem.

my code is listed below

```
-- ALLOCATE FRT Revenue BASED ON TOTAL REVENUE
   CASE
     WHEN (SUM(SOP2.XTNDPRCE) OVER(PARTITION BY SOP1.SOPNUMBE))!=0 THEN
           (SOP2.XTNDPRCE/(SUM(SOP2.XTNDPRCE) OVER(PARTITION BY SOP1.SOPNUMBE))) * SOP1.FRTAMNT
           else 0
    END as [FrtPrice],

   -- ALLOCATE FRT COSTS BASED ON TOTAL REVENUE
   CASE
     WHEN (SUM(SOP2.XTNDPRCE) OVER(PARTITION BY SOP1.SOPNUMBE))!=0 THEN
           (SOP2.XTNDPRCE/(SUM(SOP2.XTNDPRCE) OVER(PARTITION BY SOP1.SOPNUMBE))) *     
           --Calculate default Frt cost based on Current Invoice Number
                (SELECT 
                    CASE Isnumeric(rtriM(ltrim(f.USRDEF04)))
                        WHEN 1 THEN
                            Cast(F.USRDEF04 as float) 
                        ELSE NULL
                    END AS ActFrtCost 
                    FROM SOP10106 f 
                    WHERE f.SOPTYPE= SOP1.SOPTYPE AND f.SOPNUMBE = SOP1.SOPNUMBE)              
           else 0
    END as [FrtPrice],
```

SOP1 is my Invoice Header, SOP2 is my Invoice Detail, SOP10106 has my freight costs in a custom field as a varchar.  Some rows in SOP10106 have text but the ones with numeric values are my freight costs.
Basically, I am trying to allocate freight costs across all line items for each invoice.

Everything I have tried still leads to the rather annoying 'Error Converting' message.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3 Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: What is the whole error message?

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3  Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: What are the data types of `XTNDPRCE`, `SOPNUMBE` and `FRTAMNT`?... Actually... `USRDEF04` is the only one you explicitly cast as float.  What is its data type?

Comment: xtndprce is numeric(9,5), sopnumbre is varchar(31) and frtamnt is numeric(9,5)

Comment: You `trim` when you check `isnumeric`, but you dont when you cast, what does it do when you change it?

Comment: Still got the same error after trimming the cast().  I hate Great Plains 2010!

Comment: Are you using management studio?  If so, you can double click on the error and it will take you to the closest point to the error.  What line does it take you to?

Comment: Takes me to my top SELECT.

Comment: How about if you broke each of these case statements into their own select.  Instead of trying to debug them as one, you can take it piece by piece.  Its probably some bad data more than bad code.

Comment: I'm looking at this a little closer and there may be bigger problems here.  Trying to multiply a select statement is going to get you into trouble.

Comment: What about the types of `f.SOPTYPE= SOP1.SOPTYPE` are those float and varchar?

Comment: I wonder if it would be more efficient to create a temp table?  Thought I still have the issue of a really bad data in the resultant dataset from SOP10106.  Thinking now it may be better to do an update on the table to inject the freight cost in.

Comment: SOPTYPE is an integer

Comment: That is a fine idea.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Will keep you posted when I figure this out. Wish I knew SQL better.  There has to be some elegant solution that eludes me.

Comment: I think elegant solutions are out there.  They do require elegant questions tho.  Perhaps you could break down your code a bit more to try to get to the heart of the problem quicker.  All said tho, I'm sure a refactor is a great solution.